# How to add style to a radio button in play 2 for Scala?

Tags: css, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following code:

```
@inputRadioGroup(  
      registrationForm("gender"),
     options = Seq("M"->"Male","F"->"Female"),
     '_label -> "Gender",
     '_error -> registrationForm("gender").
            error.map(_.withMessage("select gender")))
```

These lines output a radio button in unformatted way.
How can I format it in play 2?

Answer (score 3):

If you add an option `'_class -> "myclassname"`, then the `<dl>` tag which contains the radio button group will have that class name. The rest is CSS. :)

```
@inputRadioGroup(
    registrationForm("gender"),
    options = Seq("M"->"Male","F"->"Female"),
    '_label -> "Gender",
    '_error -> myform("gender").
        error.map(_.withMessage("select gender")),
    '_class -> "myclassname")
```

Generated HTML:

```
<dl class="myclassname " id="gender_field">
    <dt><label for="gender">Gender</label></dt>
    <dd>
  <span class="buttonset" id="gender">

      <input type="radio" id="gender_M" name="gender" value="M"  >
      <label for="gender_M">Male</label>

      <input type="radio" id="gender_F" name="gender" value="F"  >
      <label for="gender_F">Female</label>

  </span>
</dd>
```

If you don't want to format the radio group via CSS, but rather change the generated HTML completely, there's the possibility of [writing your own form helper template](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaFormHelpers) (or, you know, you could insert the HTML for the radio group by hand).